# How to parse JSON with Arabic and HTML tags inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, webservice-client

I am calling an ASMX web service using XMLHttpRequest. It was working fine until they updated their data with Arabic language and I noticed the response text has some HTML tags inside like the following:

> {"articles":[{"id":"198715","name":"المستقبل والاشتراكي يقاطعان: ساعات
>   على الحسم","date":"Mon 13 May 2013 - 5:11:00
>   PM","description":"
>
> ساعات على الجلسة العامة المصيرية تمر سريعة في
>   الجدول الزمني لقوى 14 آذار غير المتوافقة حتى اللحظة على قانون يخرجها
>   منتصرة، اقله، امام الرأي العام...
>
> انقسام عامودي، تظهّر أكثر بعد
>   انتهاء اجتماع هيئة مكتب مجلس النواب من دون اتفاق وبالتالي الابقاء على
>   \"الاقتراح الارثوذكسي\" بندا وحيدا على جدول اعمال الجلسة العامة في 15
>   أيار.
>
> عدم الاتفاق تبعه اتفاق على عدم المشاركة في الجلسة من قبل
>   تيار المستقبل ومعه الاشتراكي والنواب المستقلون، فيما تبقي \"الكتائب\"
>   على صمتها، وكذلك \"القوات\".
>
> موقف المستقبل اوضحه النائب
>   احمد فتفت في حديث لوكالة \"المركزية\" حيث جدد التأكيد ان القانون
>   \"الارثوذكسي\" غير شرعي لانه لم يقرّ في مكتب المجلس، مشيراً الى ان
>   \"الرئيس نبيه بري تجاوز صلاحياته في هذا الموضوع، وتجاوز كل الاعراف
>   التي كنّا نتعاطى بها حتى اليوم.
>
> وكان فتفت زار ومستشار
>   الرئيس سعد الحريري محمد شطح، رئيس حزب \"الكتائب\" أمين الجميل في بيت
>   الكتائب المركزي في الصيفي، حيث \"تم التباحث بالأوضاع العامة، خصوصا
>   موضوع قانون الإنتخابات\"، من دون ان تتوضح الرؤية الكتائبية.
>
> الى ذلك، فقد اكد امين سر هيئة المكتب النائب مروان حمادة ان \"اي
>   جدول توزعه امانة المجلس من دون اقراره المسبق في هيئة المكتب يعتبر غير
>   قانوني ومخالفا للنظام الداخلي\"، مشددا على ان \"عقد الجلسة في هذا
>   الشكل يجعلها غير ميثاقية\".
>
> تزامنا، رد المجلس الدستوري
>   طلب إبطال تعليق المهل في قانون الانتخاب وقبل المراجعة الواردة في
>   المهلة
>   القانونية.
>
> ","mainImage":"http://mytv.com/pictures/articles/130513061232124.jpg","source":"","sourceImage":"","author":"","authorImage":"","keywords":[{"title":""}],"photos":[],"videos":[]}

And here is my calling function:

```
smart.apiRequestSync = function(host,operation,param,baseEntity, callBack){
  var url = "";
  var querystr='';
  if (req != null)
    req.destroy();
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
      if (req.responseText.overrideMimeType) {
        req.responseText.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      }
      var returnResult = req.responseText;
      //returnResult=returnResult.replace(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi, '');
      alert(returnResult);
      var result = null;
      if (baseEntity == "" || typeof(baseEntity) == "undefined")
        result= $j.parseJSON(returnResult);
      else {
        result= $j.parseJSON(returnResult);
        result = result[baseEntity];
      }
      callBack(result);
    }
  }
  for(var i=0; i < param.length;i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {
      querystr += param[i];
    } else {
      if(i==((param.length)-1)) {
        querystr +='='+param[i]
      } else {
        querystr +='='+param[i]+'&';
      }
    }
  }
  //HOST//operation//?par1=value1 &par2=val2.....parN=valN
  url=host+operation+querystr;
  try{
    var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8";
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    req.send();
  } catch (err){}
};
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

Anybody knows how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't care about encoding.

```
{"articles":[{"id":"198715","name":"المستقبل والاشتراكي يقاطعان: ساعاتعلى الحسم","date":"Mon 13 May 2013 - 5:11:00PM","description":"<p>ساعات على الجلسة العامة المصيرية تمر سريعة فيالجدول الزمني لقوى 14 آذار غير المتوافقة حتى اللحظة على قانون يخرجهامنتصرة، اقله، امام الرأي العام...</p><p>انقسام عامودي، تظهّر أكثر بعدانتهاء اجتماع هيئة مكتب مجلس النواب من دون اتفاق وبالتالي الابقاء على\"الاقتراح الارثوذكسي\" بندا وحيدا على جدول اعمال الجلسة العامة في 15أيار.</p><p>عدم الاتفاق تبعه اتفاق على عدم المشاركة في الجلسة من قبلتيار المستقبل ومعه الاشتراكي والنواب المستقلون، فيما تبقي \"الكتائب\"على صمتها، وكذلك \"القوات\".</p><p</p><p>موقف المستقبل اوضحه النائباحمد فتفت في حديث لوكالة \"المركزية\" حيث جدد التأكيد ان القانون\"الارثوذكسي\" غير شرعي لانه لم يقرّ في مكتب المجلس، مشيراً الى ان\"الرئيس نبيه بري تجاوز صلاحياته في هذا الموضوع، وتجاوز كل الاعرافالتي كنّا نتعاطى بها حتى اليوم.</p><p</p><p>وكان فتفت زار ومستشارالرئيس سعد الحريري محمد شطح، رئيس حزب \"الكتائب\" أمين الجميل في بيتالكتائب المركزي في الصيفي، حيث \"تم التباحث بالأوضاع العامة، خصوصاموضوع قانون الإنتخابات\"، من دون ان تتوضح الرؤية الكتائبية.</p><p></p><p>الى ذلك، فقد اكد امين سر هيئة المكتب النائب مروان حمادة ان \"ايجدول توزعه امانة المجلس من دون اقراره المسبق في هيئة المكتب يعتبر غيرقانوني ومخالفا للنظام الداخلي\"، مشددا على ان \"عقد الجلسة في هذاالشكل يجعلها غير ميثاقية\".</p><p</p><p>تزامنا، رد المجلس الدستوريطلب إبطال تعليق المهل في قانون الانتخاب وقبل المراجعة الواردة فيالمهلةالقانونية.</p>","mainImage":"http://mytv.com/pictures/articles/130513061232124.jpg","source":"","sourceImage":"","author":"","authorImage":"","keywords":[{"title":""}],"photos":[],"videos":[]}]}
```

http://jsonlint.com/ seems to think this is valid. **I added a missing `]` and `}` at the end**

Comment: I have check the link and it is give me so errors in the json format

Comment: No, it's not, the JSON is fine -- if you add the missing `]` and `}`.

Comment: what should I do right now , is it possible to ignore this errors in json format

Comment: Parse error on line 73:
...     "description": "<p>قتل ما لا يقل عن
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: after I added ]} at the end

Comment: Line 73? The input you gave does not have 73 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have actual newline control characters inside of strings in JSON. All newlines need to be converted to `\n` or removed.

You are also missing the end of the array and root object:

```
  ]
}
```

Comment: what tag do you mean "newlines"

Comment: Your string is on multiple lines. So within the string there are [newline control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) which need to be converted to `\n`. Try to make the `"description"` property all on one line. Otherwise you'll have to go through and convert before the JSON is parsed. Only the newlines inside the quotes matter.